# Java Web Start deploy on Windows startup

Tags: java, deployment, java-web-start

I have a Java application that I'm about to begin to use Web Start to deploy. But a new demand has made me rethink this, as I'm now required to add a piece of functionality that allows the end user to select whether or not they'd like to run this program on startup (of Windows, not cross-platform). But I'd still like to shy away from making this run as a service. Is there any way that this can be accomplished using Web Start, or should I explore other options to deploy this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It actually works to put a this in the jnlp-file:

```
<shortcut online="true">
    <desktop/>
    <menu submenu="Startup"/>
</shortcut>
```

But that still would only work with English windows versions. German is "Autostart", Spanish was "Iniciar" I think. So it causes basically the same headache as the way via the IntegrationService.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but I wonder if you could use the new JNLP [IntegrationService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#IntegrationService) in combination with the [javaws](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#batch) command line program.  The idea being to programmatically create a shortcut in the Windows startup group (although that location is dependent on specific Windows version).

Answer (score 1):

To get around the language problem for the Startup folder just use the registry. Here is some code that should work. This calls reg.exe to make registry changes.

```
public class StartupCreator {

    public static void setupStartupOnWindows(String jnlpUrl, String applicationName) throws Exception {
        String foundJavaWsPath = findJavaWsOnWindows();
        String cmd = foundJavaWsPath + " -Xnosplash \"" + jnlpUrl + "\"";
        setRegKey("HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", applicationName, cmd);
    }

    public static String findJavaWsOnWindows() {
    // The paths where it will look for java
    String[] paths = {
        // first use the JRE that was used to launch this app, it will probably not reach the below paths
        System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "javaws.exe",
        // it must check for the 64 bit path first because inside a 32-bit process system32 is actually syswow64
        // 64 bit machine with 32 bit JRE
        System.getenv("SYSTEMROOT") + File.separator + "syswow64" + File.separator + "javaws.exe",
        // 32 bit machine with 32 bit JRE or 64 bit machine with 64 bit JRE
        System.getenv("SYSTEMROOT") + File.separator + "system32" + File.separator + "javaws.exe",};
        return findJavaWsInPaths(paths);
    }

    public static String findJavaWsInPaths(String[] paths) throws RuntimeException {
        String foundJavaWsPath = null;
        for (String p : paths) {
            File f = new File(p);
            if (f.exists()) {
                foundJavaWsPath = p;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundJavaWsPath == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find path for javaws executable");
        }
        return foundJavaWsPath;
    }

    public static String setRegKey(String location, String regKey, String regValue) throws Exception {
        String regCommand = "add \"" + location + "\" /v \"" + regKey + "\" /f /d \"" + regValue + "\"";

        return doReg(regCommand);
    }

    public static String doReg(String regCommand) throws Exception {

        final String REG_UTIL = "reg";
        final String regUtilCmd = REG_UTIL + " " + regCommand;
        return runProcess(regUtilCmd);
    }

    public static String runProcess(final String regUtilCmd) throws Exception {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(regUtilCmd);

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
            sw.write(c);
        }
        String result = sw.toString();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (process.exitValue() == -1) {
            throw new Exception("REG QUERY command returned with exit code -1");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! A little slow maybe (application is unresponsive for a few seconds, I think it might be because of this code), but works. Now I need something to put my application itself in autostart (not over the JNLP file)...

Comment: Run the code via SwingWorker and it will run in the background.